# sort Object.String with Java

Tags: java

I have a Object:

```
public class ListAnnotationsOrigin implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8443084209405942551L;

@JsonProperty("opcombo")
private List<opcombo> listComboOp;

@JsonProperty("vicombo")
private List<vicombo> listComboVi;

@JsonProperty("vicombo")
private String vicombo;

@JsonProperty("viversion")
private String idVersionVi;

@JsonProperty("closed")
private String closed;

@JsonProperty("params")
private List<SegmentOrigin> listSegmentOrigin; // <-- here

   // getters,setters etc.
```

I want sort listSegmentOrigin

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SegmentOrigin")
public class SegmentOrigin implements Comparable<T>{ // <-- ERROR 

 ....

    @JsonProperty("idSegment")
    private String idSegment;

    public int compareTo(SegmentOrigin arg0) {
      if (this.getIdSegment().compareTo(arg0.getIdSegment())) { // <<--ERROR type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;   
      }
    }
}
```

In my controller->

```
ListAnnotationsOrigin list = this.getListAnnotationsOrigin ();
return Collections.sort((List<SegmentOrigin>) list.getListSegmentOrigin());
```

I send my List from ListAnnotationsOrigin in an orderly manner, Then when I implements  Comparable{ I get red line "implements methods unics"
I import ->  `public int compareTo(SegmentOrigin arg0) { ...` and I get other error, thanks.

Comment: `compareTo()` returns an int, and not a boolean. `return this.getIdSegment().compareTo(arg0.getIdSegment())` should do the work.

Comment: Please attach the error stacktrace

Comment: At `Comparable<T>` instead of `T` use type which should be compared, in your case `SegmentOrigin`.

Comment: @Benoit Your suggested solution looks right, but problem description isn't. OP isn't *returning* boolean, problem here is that `if(condition)` expect at `condition` expression which could be *evaluated* as boolean, but what OP has evaluates to `int`.

Comment: OK, I changed T for SegmentOrigin and changed my if. Now I get error in my return from controller. "Cannot return a void result"

Comment: please, checked my updated.

Comment: `sort` doesn't return anything, it just sorts passed array so `return ..sort(list);` is like `return void` which makes no sense here. Why do you have `return` there anyway? If you want to return sorted list you can first sort it, and then return it `sort(list); return list;`

Comment: BTW you shouldn't change your question into something which invalidates already posted answers. If you have new problem ask about it in new question.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please use `edit` option only to *clarify* your problem, not to *change* it into new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity should look like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SegmentOrigin")
public class SegmentOrigin implements Comparable<SegmentOrigin>{

    @JsonProperty("idSegment")
    private String idSegment;

    public int compareTo(SegmentOrigin arg0) {
        return this.getIdSegment().compareTo(arg0.getIdSegment()); // Check nullity if needed
    }
}
```

`implements Comparable<SegmentOrigin>` means that your object can be compared with another SegmentOrigin object.

Comment: OK, I changed T for SegmentOrigin and changed my if. Now I get error in my return from controller. "Cannot return a void result"